# How to structure a stacked form with WPF XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

On my Window, I've got a `GroupBox`. I'd like to build out a horizontally aligned form inside of that `GroupBox`. By horizontally aligned, I mean a form where the label and the input reside on the same grid row or x axis. Separate form labels + inputs reside on their own row.

Since a `GroupBox` can only have one child content, I assume I need to either use a `Grid` or `StackPanel`. I'm trying to use a `StackPanel` because that seems simpler and should achieve what I'm aiming for.

The issue I'm trying to figure out is how to group the input and label into one unit so they can reside horizontally next to each other, but stack vertically as a pair within the `StackPanel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably best to use a `Grid` that way you an get the labels and inputs to line up vertically. While it's not impossible with a stack panel it's a whole lot harder. If you set the grid's `RowDefinition` heights to "Auto" the grid will only be as tall as it needs to be:

```
<GroupBox>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Label1"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Input1}"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Label2"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Input2}"/>
        etc.
    </Grid>
</GroupBox>
```

You'll probably need to play around with margins and/or padding and horizontal alignments to get the layout exactly how you want it, but this should give you the control you need to achieve what you want.

Comment: It's now apparent to me that there are many approaches to this. While my initial question was regarding a `StackPanel`, I feel that a `Grid` feels more flexible but more importantly solves the initial question with the least amount of changes to default settings. I tried out the `StackPanel` first but found that a lot of customization was needing to achieve what the `Grid` basically provides by default, regarding layout and sizing of child components. The `Grid` is more verbose at the end of the day, but seems like a good approach.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a stackpanel with orientation equal to vertical inside your groupbox and inside that stackpanel you can have another stackpanel with orientation equal to horizantal for your label and input just like following sample code.

```html
<GroupBox Header="Sample GroupBox">
  <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <StackPanel Name="input1" Orientation="Horizontal">
      <Label Content="input1"/>
      <TextBox/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Name="input2" Orientation="Horizontal">
      <Label Content="input2"/>
      <TextBox/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Name="input3" Orientation="Horizontal">
      <Label Content="input3"/>
      <TextBox/>
    </StackPanel>
  </StackPanel>
</GroupBox>
```

Comment: This is fine if you don't want the labels and inputs to line up vertically, but you'll need to do a lot of work and probably hard code values if you do.

Answer (score 1):

One feature you might find useful is grid shared size scope. It can help you align elements in multiple different Grids, by sharing their column\row sizes, like this:

```
<GroupBox Header="Sample GroupBox">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"  SharedSizeGroup="firstGroup" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"  SharedSizeGroup="secondGroup" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Content="input11" Grid.Column="0" />
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Width="100"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"  SharedSizeGroup="firstGroup" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"  SharedSizeGroup="secondGroup" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Content="input2222222" Grid.Column="0" />
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"  SharedSizeGroup="firstGroup" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"  SharedSizeGroup="secondGroup" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Content="input3333333333333" Grid.Column="0" />
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1"/>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</GroupBox>
```

I don't say that it is necessary in the code above, but that is just example. Often, you want to use grid in for example ItemTemplate of ItemsControl, and you want all items to be aligned. Here shared size scope might help.